# Is there an advantage to authoring classic COM components versus windows runtime classes?

Tags: uwp, com, c++-winrt

My goal is to author a component that is callable from a C# application. The component in question contains DX12 code as well as some xaml code that I authored in a C++/WinRT project. I want to extract that code to put it inside a component. I see that there is two different ways to do this:

1) Authoring a classic COM component as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-coclasses

2) Authoring a windows runtime class as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-apis

What are the reasons somebody would choose option #1 instead of #2?

Comment: It just is not very arbitrary, whether you intend the client code to target the legacy desktop or UWP is a pretty big deal to the client programmer.  But if you develop the component with C++/WinRT and xaml then there is no choice, the client programmer *must* target UWP and only 2) qualifies.

Comment: You are reading something into the documentation, that's not there. It's possible to use the C++/WinRT library to implement COM classes (that don't have the additional 3 `IInspectable` interface methods). This doesn't mean that COM and the Windows Runtime can be used interchangeably. They are different platforms. You need to know, which one you want to target. Since you are using XAML, it's pretty much a given, that you cannot use classic COM to expose your interfaces (unless you want to go down the XAML islands route).